# How to keep array of a list while screen rotation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am using this implementation to keep lists after screen rotation:

```
@Composable
fun <T : Any> rememberMutableStateListOf(vararg elements: T): SnapshotStateList<T> {
    return rememberSaveable(
        saver = listSaver(
            save = { stateList -> stateList.toList() },
            restore = { list -> list.toMutableStateList() }
        )
    ) {
        elements.toList().toMutableStateList()
    }
}
```

This works well with objects, e.g.:

```
val items = rememberMutableStateListOf<Item>()
```

However, I also has a use case when I need to keep a list of objects within the saveable like:

```
val items = rememberMutableStateListOf<List<Item>>()
```

which does not keep list after screen rotation. How could I extend that implementation to cover requirements of use case?